# sqlserver - Insert from xml generated with `select for xml`

Tags: sql-server, select, xml, merge

Is there a simple way to create an XML (file, variable, value in column, whatever) with `select * from table for xml ...` and later *automatically* insert this data into identical table in different database? Something like `insert into table from xml ...`. All solutions I can find require providing column names explicitly.

What I want in the end is a simple thing - I have Java service connecting to the database. It is able to download new dictionary data and insert (merge) it into specific tables. Currently there are quite a few such tables and we have separate procedures for them, all specifying columns names and so on. This is getting out of hand and I'm looking for some way of simplifying it.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2118/scripts-to-use-xml-to-insert-and-update-rows-in-a-sql-server-table/)?

Comment: I guess so, but mother of God! I really hope that during 11 years that passed since text that you linked was written things have changed, as I'm unable to understand how it works. Thank a lot anyway.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the best way to do it would be via OPENXML, as described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989395/convert-xml-to-table-sql-server).

Comment: Could you please provide more context on your current schema and workflow? Do all the Tables have the same columns or different columns? Do all the procedures do the same logic or there's different logic per table? Right now what you described doesn't sound like a problem, or if it is one, it's unclear how **XML** would help. If anything you may want to use **Dynamic SQL** instead, or another feature like **Triggers** but I'm not 100% sure on what your actual problem is.

Comment: Assume tables T1, T2... Tn on servers S1, S2... Sn. Tn on server Sm is identical to table Tn on other servers. All procedures updating it are nearly identical `with ... merge ... when matched then update set <a lot of columns>`. Now that you said `it's unclear how XML would help` I see that main problem is still there - I won't be able to avoid specifying columns names in `update` or `insert` sub-clauses in `merge`. It seems that dynamic SQL is the only solution - or maybe now, maybe I could automatically generate procedure for each table. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @AMtwo The scripts in that article are a horror show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended with.

Assuming that data is read from the table using the following:

```sql
select * from someTable where st_id between 100 and 200
for xml path, root('rows')
```

I get this data from one server and store it as a tuple (schema, table, keys, xml), where:

- `schema` is schema name (e.g. `dbo`)
- `table` is table name (e.g. `someTable`)
- `keys` is comma-separated list of "keys" (columns used for `<match>` in `merge ... on <match>`, e.g. `st_id` in example above, if there are more keys they should be `passed,like,this`)
- `xml` is data as an xml (easy)

This data is then passed to some other server, where there is one function and one procedure defined.

Function `tools.GenerateXMLMergerForTable` creates body (whole declaration in fact) of procedure used for merging data read from `xml` into table `table` in schema `schema` using parsed string `keys` as `<match>`.

Procedure `tools.createXMLMergerForTable` executes aforementioned function and creates procedure that takes single parameter (of type XML) and merges data read from it into table that it was configured for.

T-SQL follows:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION tools.GenerateXMLMergerForTable 
(
@tableschema nvarchar(max), @tablename nvarchar(max), @matchcols nvarchar(max), @procname nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @str nvarchar(max) = '
    create or alter procedure tools.sp_AutoMergerForTableXXXPROCEDURENAMEXXX @x xml
    as
    begin
        begin try
            DECLARE @handle INT, @PrepareXmlStatus INT  

            EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @x

            merge XXXTABLENAMEXXX as tgt
            using (SELECT  * FROM OPENXML(@handle, ''/rows/row'', 2) WITH XXXTABLENAMEXXX)
                as src (XXXFULLCOLUMNLISTXXX)
            on XXXMATCHLISTXXX
            when matched 
                then update set
                    XXXSETLISTXXX
            when not matched by target
                then
                    insert (XXXFULLCOLUMNLISTXXX)
                    values (XXXFULLCOLUMNLISTXXX);
            EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
        end try
        begin catch
        end catch
    end
    '

    declare @collist nvarchar(max) = '', @setlist nvarchar(max) = '', @matchlist nvarchar(max) = '', @fullcollist nvarchar(max) = ''

    select @collist = @collist + quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
        , @setlist = @setlist + quotename(column_name) + ' = src.' + quotename(column_name) + ', '
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableschema and TABLE_NAME = @tablename and COLUMN_NAME not in (select * from string_split(@matchcols, ','))
    order by ordinal_position

    select @fullcollist = @fullcollist + quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = @tableschema and TABLE_NAME = @tablename
    order by ordinal_position

    select @matchlist = @matchlist + 'tgt.' + QUOTENAME(trim(value)) + '=src.' + QUOTENAME(trim(value)) from string_split(@matchcols, ',')

    declare @result nvarchar(max) = replace(@str, 'XXXCOLUMNLISTXXX', trim(', ' from @collist))
    set @result = REPLACE(@result, 'XXXSETLISTXXX', trim(', ' from @setlist))
    set @result = REPLACE(@result, 'XXXTABLENAMEXXX', @tablename)
    set @result = REPLACE(@result, 'XXXMATCHLISTXXX', REPLACE(trim(@matchlist), ' ', ' and '))
    set @result = REPLACE(@result, 'XXXPROCEDURENAMEXXX', @procname)
    set @result = REPLACE(@result, 'XXXFULLCOLUMNLISTXXX', trim(', ' from @fullcollist))

    RETURN @result

END
GO

create or alter procedure tools.createXMLMergerForTable @schema nvarchar(max), @table nvarchar(max), @matchcols nvarchar(max), @procsuffix nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @body nvarchar(max) = tools.GenerateXMLMergerForTable(@schema, @table, @matchcols, @procsuffix)
    exec sp_executesql @body
end

go
```

Java code simply reads tuple defined above, inserts parameters that it knows off, creates random suffix, creates merging procedure, executes it using `xml` from The Tuple and drops previously created procedure.

It *seems* to work as advertised, though no guarantees are provided.

NOTE: it is assumed that function, procedure and subsequently created procedures live in schema `tools`.

NOTE 2: It is possible that you will get information about `string_split` object not found, if so then just do:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE <your database name> 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;
```

For reasons see documentation of [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and how to [change compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15).